# Java Play Ebean - how to use Expression Expr.Or() or like that

Tags: java, playframework, expression, ebean

I have a class, that use ebean in Java Play Framework.
I try use `Expression Expr.Or()` and I want to return type is `PageList<News>`

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "news")
public class News extends Model {

@Id
@Column(name = "news_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long newsId; // ID

@Column(name = "title")
public String title; // タイトル

@Lob
@Column(name = "article")
public String article; // 記事内容

@Column(name = "view_count")
public Integer viewCount = 0; // 閲覧数

@Column(name = "category")
public Integer category; // 1:キャリア 2: スキル 3:テクノロジー

@Column(name = "state")
public Boolean state = false; // 状況 false:下書き true: 公開

@Column(name = "recommend")
public Boolean recommend = false; // おすすめ false:なし true:おすすめ

@Column(name = "created")
@CreatedTimestamp
public Date created; // 登録び

@Column(name = "modified")
@UpdatedTimestamp
public Date modified; // 更新日

@Lob
@Column(name = "image")
public String image; // 画像

@Column(name = "is_deleted")
public Boolean isDeleted = false;

}
```

In Play Ebean, I want to find news like query

```java
SELECT * FROM NEWS
WHERE title LIE '%?%' 
OR article LIKE '%?%'
OR category LIKE '%?%'
OR state = ?
OR recommend = '?
OR created = '?
```

So, how I can write code. I try use `Expression Expr.Or()` but `Expression Expr.Or()` but this can use only two expressions. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try nested Expr.or() statements

```
 Ebean.find(News.class).where().or(
    Expr.or( Expr.like("title", "%?%"), Expr.like("article", "%?%")),
    Expr.or(Expr.like("category", "%?%"),Expr.like("state","?"))
  );
```